# Хранилище для многостроковых ресурсов с форматированием

Tags: java, properties

Есть некоторые текстовые ресурсы:

```
Это пример строки
  -с форматированием и отступами
    -лорем ипсум долор
Еще строка
```

Мне нужно некоторое хранилище для набора таких ресурсов, чтобы форматирование не портилось, не елись пробелы и все это можно было удобно редактировать. И чтобы все это можно было получить по ключу, в идеале удобный способ редактирования их для нескольких языков

Я пробовал хранить их в обычных property файлах, но всегда съедаются пробелы или переносы строк.
Создал свой вариант для хранения этих строк с метками вроде:

```
$label:
    Это пример строки
      -с форматированием и отступами
        -лорем ипсум долор
    Еще строка
```

Но редактирование таких файлов превращается в ад. Прошу помочь с вариантами.

Comment: Так а чем БД не устраивает?

Comment: @ezhov_da тем, что мое приложение базу данных не использует

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В файле .properties можно использовать обратную косую черту «\» для обозначения нужных пробелов:

```
myProperty=Это пример строки\n\
\    -с форматированием и отступами\n\
\        -лорем ипсум долор\n\
Еще строка
```

Это вскользь упомянуто в документации к [`Properties.load`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load(java.io.Reader)):

> The key contains all of the characters in the line starting with the first non-white space character and up to, but not including, the first unescaped '=', ':', or white space character other than a line terminator. **All of these key termination characters may be included in the key by escaping them with a preceding backslash character;** ...

Comment: Ну что ж. Это работает. Теперь проблема только в том, что стандартный ResourceBundle editor в idea не знает об этой возможности и ставить умеет либо ничего, либо двойной слеш \\. Нда

Comment: @SerhiiDikobrazko Странно. Среды под рукой нет и посмотреть не могу, к сожалению. Альтернатива: можно ставить [пустой пробел](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space) через юникод(`\u200b`) или сам по себе. Эффект будет такой же, т.к. `Properties` пропускает только ограниченный набор пробельных символов.

Comment: @defaultlocaleЭтот вариант тоже работает. К слову, есть еще вариант добавлять нужные пробелы в конце строки после знака переноса, они будут отображаться на второй строке в начале, но это только добавляет проблем

Comment: @SerhiiDikobrazko Да, прям хороших вариантов нет. Есть еще вариант: написать свой маппер на XML/JSON/YAML, но я бы не сказал, что редактировать их будет намного легче. Если таких строк много и они сложные, то можно посмотреть на библиотеки шаблонов (например [StringTemplate](https://www.stringtemplate.org/)). Или перенести все в БД (можно локальную вроде H2/MapDB/Derby) и настраивать через приложение.

Comment: Да. Спасибо за все варианты. Есть с чем работать)

Answer (score 1):

В общем, создал такую затычку [FormattedProperties](https://gist.github.com/dikhim/40c76b0bc9042c5bdd828c5a3e73ddcb)
Класс работает аналогично обычному Properties, но только не пропускает пробелы в начале строки. Потому, если в файле указать такой кусок текста

```
myProperty=Это пример строки\n\
    -с форматированием и отступами\n\
        -лорем ипсум долор\n\
Еще строка
```

Пробелы в начале строки остануться и можно задавать форматированный текст.
Это нарушает соглашение о том, как вообще должен работать файл .properties, да и не безопасно. Но если других вариантов нет...

Comment: Почему не использовать XML?